Retrieve value from external API to arch view in Odoo 16
I would like to add a new tab in res.partner form with data retrieved from an external API. So I created a custom addon with this view :
<record id = "my_record" model = "ir.ui.view">
        <field name = "name">Custom Tab</field>
        <field name = "model">res.partner</field>
        <field name = "inherit_id" ref = "base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name = "arch" type = "xml">
            <xpath expr="//page[@name='internal_notes']" position='after'>
                <page string='My new tab'>
                    <!-- Get the data in dictionary from model -->
                </page>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

Then I got my model:
from odoo import models
import json
import random
import urllib.request
class Facturation(models.Model):    
  _inherit = 'res.partner'
   def json_rpc(self):      
   req = urllib.request.Request(url='myurl',headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"})      
   reply = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('UTF-8'))      
   if reply.get("error"):        
     raise Exception(reply["error"])       
   return {        
      'key1': reply['value1'],        
      'key2': reply['value2']      
   }

Everything works fine but now I would like to know how to display the dictionary with value1 and value2 and loop through it in my arch view?
Thanks a lot
